# c programming encounters Segmentation fault (core dumped)

Tags: c

I am trying to allocate a big block of memory.

I ran this code firt,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    long i;
    long n = 50000;
    printf("trying to malloc %ld memory. ", n);
    long *ptr;
    ptr = (long*) malloc(n * sizeof(int));
    if(ptr == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error! memory not allocated.");
        exit(0);
    }
    for(i = 0; i < n; ++i)
    {
        *(ptr+2*i) = 9;
    }
    for(i = 0; i < 5; ++i)
    {
        printf("%ld ", *(ptr+2*i)); 
    }
    return 0;
}
```

and then I got this error

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

I know this "you are accessing memory that does not belong to you.", but why

PS:

`long n = 5000;` works well

Comment: Do you know that `*(ptr+2*i)` can be written more clearly as `ptr[2*i]`? I'm curious where people learn to prefer that address arithmetic notation.

Comment: @Blastfurnace Probably their professors. If my professor does that when I go to college I might leave a note for him explaining that that's not great practice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you have a pointer to a datatype, adding 1 to that pointer will actually offset the address by however large the datatype is. If I have a pointer to an integer array at `0x0000`, doing `myArray += 1;` will result in my pointer having the value of `0x0004` (assuming an integer is 4 bytes on my system)

Knowing this, you can see how the line `*(ptr+2*i)` will go out of the bounds of your array for all values of `i` greater than `i/2`

Normally, since you are dynamically creating this array, writing to these addresses would just corrupt heap memory and not cause a segfault. The problem is that your program is going so far out of bounds, it is past the heap and going into memory that doesn't belong to your program. This is why it segfaults for 50000 and not 5000.

Comment: For the unique insight into his exact erroneous line of thinking I'm not tagging a dupe on this.

Comment: @Joshua I think you should. There's plenty of other questions on Stack Overflow with much better answers than people can give on this one.